# Umask doesn't change after reboot

Tags: permission, smb

I'm new to umask so please correct me if i'm wrong.

We have a mac OS X file server at work with multiple SMB shares. Whenever users create files, they get created as -rw-r--r-- as this is the default umask (022). I want to change it to (002) so created files will have -rw-rw---- as default. This way all users in the same group can access the files.

Apple [advises](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684) to change umask like this:

> `sudo launchctl config user umask nnn`

After doing `sudo launchctl config user umask 002` I got the following message:

> `Configuration applied. You must reboot for changes to take effect.`

I rebooted and got the following:

> `$ umask`
> `0022`

what am I doing wrong, please advise.

I'm running OS X Server 10.10.3 Yosemite with Server.app 4.1

Comment: What do `cat /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist` and `ls ...` show?

Comment: I think this is the holy grail I've been looking for...  The first one shows umask = 0. Should I set this to 002?

Comment: I updated the file, rebooted but the command umask still returns 0022. Even if I check the file now it shows <integer>002</integer>.

Comment: That is not the problem. The .plist get's updated but the command `umask` doesn't return the value. Also, try to do `sudo launchctl config user umask 022` you'll see that the value in the plist file changes to 18 so I don't think these are interchangeable. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I meant: I ran the command `sudo launchctl config user umask 002` in 10.10.5 with no problem (-> `umask` shows 0002) and the user.plist was updated properly to .... <integer>002</integer>.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess but I think it's an error in 10.10.3 which is solved in 10.10.5 (or maybe 10.10.4) because none of my 10.10.5 hosts show your 10.10.3 behavior.

So I recommend to update to 10.10.5/4.1.5.

BTW the integer in /var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist is calculated by [converting](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter) the three binary "triplets" to a decimal number:

```
002 = 000 000 010 =   2
022 = 000 010 010 =  18
666 = 110 110 110 = 438
```